# Let $q$, $p$ be distinct primes. Determine unique $n$ in $\{q, q+1, \ldots, q+p-1\}$ such that $\gcd(p, n) > 1$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-progressions, reduced-residue-system

Is there a way to determine, given distinct primes $q, p$, the unique $n \in \{q, q+1, \ldots, q+p-1\}$ such that $\gcd(n, p) \gt 1$?

Comment: What do you mean by "determine"?

Comment: Algorithm or formula.

Comment: lol, I think I provided both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have $p$ consecutive numbers, exactly one is divisble by $p$, which is equavalent that it is not coprime to $p$.

If $p<q$ , and $s\equiv q \mod p$ with $0<s<p-1$, then take $q+p-s$

If $p>=q$ , $p=q+(p-q)$ is contained in the given set because of $0\le p-q<p-1$

In short , calculate $q$ modulo $p$ , denote the result $s$ and take $p+q-s$.

So, a formula would be $p+q- (q\mod p)$

Comment: That wasn't the question. He didn't ask to prove there is exactly one such $n$, he asked to DETERMINE it. He takes as granted (conceded) the true fact that there is exactly one such $n$.

Comment: I edited the answer. The original answer was a HINT.

Comment: It wasn't - it did not give any kind of suggestion in the direction the OP needed. It was true, but not addressing the question.

Comment: A hint does not solve the problem completely. If it does, it is not a hint anymore.

Comment: A hint gives a small (or not necessarily small) suggestion, or help, in the direction of answering the question. Your original answer (since edited) does not move the ball even a hairwidth in the direction of answering the question.

Comment: Or more succinctly: $q + (-q\mod p)$.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make much sense, but... divide $q$ by $p$:

$$q = cp + r$$

Then $n = (c+1)p$.

Does this determine $n$?

If you need a formula: $n = \lceil \frac q p \rceil \times p$.